# Do I understand the tree_hash() code correctly?

Tags: transaction-hash

```
    memcpy(ints, hashes, (2 * cnt - count) * HASH_SIZE);

    for (i = 2 * cnt - count, j = 2 * cnt - count; j < cnt; i += 2, ++j) {
      cn_fast_hash(hashes[i], 64, ints + j * HASH_SIZE);
    }
```

Isn't there a buffer overrun? `i` is going over of size of `hashes[]`.

For example - count=53, cnt=32. At j=26, i=52 buffer overrun.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a buffer overrun? `i` is going over of size of `hashes[]`.

No, it wont and isn't.

> At j=26, i=52 buffer overrun.

No. When `j=26`, `i` is **41**, so there's no buffer overrun.

Comment: Ok, you are right, thank you. But what will happened with last `hashes[52]`? Hashes are hashed by pairs, as 64 bytes, will it skipped or doubled somehow?

Comment: `i` never equals 52 in this loop and example.